# SQL - Where criteria to find names between A-F

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, where-clause, between

Simple question:

I need a solution so that I can find, lets say names, between A-F, INCLUDING all names that start with F.

If you use BETWEEN or A >= value <= F you find out that it stops at F. So I am posting this for suggestions.

**NOTE:
User will see 2 textboxes that accept a range user can type. The user refines how far to go in F boundary as such: User types in 'Fa' means the result should return: Fauder, Fail, Famber, ... etc**

I have currently 2 solutions but there's got a be a better way.

Solution 1: 
This will add 1 to outer boundary but may include result if there's a name that is single 'G', highly unlikely though.
WHERE name >= 'A' AND <= CHAR(ASCII('F') + 1)

Solution 2:
This solution appends last letter of alphabet field length times.
WHERE name >= 'A' AND <= 'FZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ'

Although the above solutions are workable, my search can be refined as such:
A to Fs (should give me everything from A to and including Fs....). With this solution #1 is broken since it works with single ascii.

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: SQL Server 2000 or later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you expand the requirement to include `A` - `Fxxx`.

```
SET @start = 'A'
SET @end   = 'Fxxx'

SELECT
  *
FROM
  table
WHERE
  (name >= @start AND name < @end)
  OR (name LIKE @end + '%')
```

Note that this does not include functions on the `name` field; such functions prevent range seeks on indexes.  However, the inclusion of the `OR` degrades the index seek too.  Although it's extra code, this actually can be more performant is some cases...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table
WHERE
  (name >= @start AND name < @end)

UNION ALL

SELECT
  *
FROM
  table
WHERE
  (name LIKE @end + '%')
```

**EDIT**

In hindsight, your *Solution 2*, although you don't like it, is probably the best.

Turning `Fxxx` to `FxxxZZZZZZZZZZ` is simple enough with `STUFF()`, provided that you know the max string length, which you should do as the database is yours.

It doesn't have any functions on the `name` field, and it doesn't use an `OR` in the `WHERE` clause.  Which means that you get a pure range seek on any index.

Performance wise, I do not think you can improve on this.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much & thank you all for responses.

Answer (score 11):

You can do:

```
WHERE name >= 'A' AND name < 'G'
```

Comment: Only if we could hard code things. I am looking for a formula. The above will also return a name that is 'G' which is incorrect.

Comment: @ActiveX - What do you mean with "a formula"?, what are the expected parameters for your query?, and no, it won't return a name that is `G`.

Comment: @ActiveX - This uses `<` rather than `<=` or `BETWEEN`.  It is a very normal and powerful pattern, that doesn't care how many characters are in the `name` field, or require any functions on the `name` field (which is important as such functions destroy the ability to use an index range seek).  Personally, this is exactly what I'd use.

Comment: This answer is preferable because it's more likely that it can make use of indices. If you use the substr() function, you're likely to get a table scan.

Comment: @Lamak: Formula so it works with different parameters. You hardcoded values into the WHERE clause. 
Expected parameters to stored procedure going to be strings, 
I just used hardcoded values for simplifying my questions
Yes it will return a name 'G' it is the way the operator works up and including the outer bounday which is G. So if your name is 'G', it will be returned.

Comment: @Dems: If I use <, that will exclude all the outer boundary, in this example 'F', Frank, Friedrich, etc. I want all 'F' be included unless the user refines how far to go in F as such: User types in 'Fa' means Fauder, Fail, Famber.

Comment: @ActiveX - The boundary in the answer is `G`, not `F`. But based on your comments I've added an answer too.  (*Please* could you add the contents of your comment to your question, it's extremely relevant.)

Comment: @ActiveX - You don't seem to understand how the `<` operator works, it **won't** return a name 'G'. Did you actually **try** the above code?, I have, and it works. You wanted to filter the letter `F` thats why I use `G` on my code

Comment: @Lamak: OOOOPS my bad! It is early in the morning, I am not fully awake. You're correct!

Comment: @Dems: OOOOPS my bad! It is early in the morning, I am not fully awake. You're correct!

Comment: The concept @Lamak is trying to introduce is inclusive/exclusive.  Often when we want a range, it is convenient to have an INCLUSIVE define of the start, and an EXCLUSIVE define of the end.  This additionally allows us to use the end from the previous query as the start of the next query.  If those parameters are in a table somewhere, the fact that the ends of queries = the starts of the next, makes writing tests to verify parameter integrity easier as well.

Comment: @jerry: I know, problem was my eyes were to shut to see '<' instead of '<='.

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
WHERE SUBSTR(name, 1, 1) >= 'A' AND SUBSTR(name, 1, 1) <= 'F'
```

Comment: Not bad. That will work but requires more programming. In my case the user can refine search to: A - Fs, or A Fxxx. I could use your approach and write some code to calculate the field length of the 2nd boundary and feed that to substr but it is becoming messy.

Comment: Works, but putting a function around the `name` field prevents index seeks, and results in a full scan.

Comment: @ActiveX - What do you mean the use can specifcy `A` - `Fxxx`?  That significantly changes the behaviour you described in your question.  Please could you update the question to include all functionality that you require?

Comment: I apologize: 2 textboxes that accept a range user can type. If the user refines how far to go in F as such: User types in 'Fa' means Fauder, Fail, Famber.

Answer (score 2):

Will this work for you:

```
select * 
from MyTable
where left(name, 1) between 'a' and 'f'
```

Comment: Works, but putting a function around the `name` field prevents index seeks, and results in a full scan.

Answer (score 2):

How much more simple can you make it?

```
WHERE NAME LIKE '[a-f]%'
```

Comment: Will work with single character value only. Not with ranges such as: A-Fa, A-Fb. I was not explicit on my question,I apologize. I have edited my question and added more detail.