# BETWEEN operator when range has texts with numbers

Tags: sql, between

I have to select data from a table using column values that contain texts with numbers, like this:

```
"SELECT Title, Category from BookList where CategoryField BETWEEN '"
  + blockCodeStart + "' AND '" + blockCodeEnd + "'";

blockCodeStart = "A25"
blockCodeEnd = "A39"
```

I understand that and could handle either texts or numbers only, but not both. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is it always 'A' or one character followed by some numbers?

Comment: There is a great post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893329/sql-where-criteria-to-find-names-between-a-f  Are you trying to do do a between based on on numbers or alpha? Obviously in this case it will take the values between the alphanumeric values.  One of the things you can do is parse the values, selecting out the numeric characters, but that would take forever in a large dataset.  What is your expected outcome?

Comment: #Paul, it is not always A. Actually, the texts range from A to Z. However, only similar texts accompany the two columns (e.g. you always Get "A + number" compared to "A + number", or "D + number" compared to "D + number"; not "A + number" compared to "B + number".
I just found that out, so looks like I only have to use SQL to select between numbers in 2 columns.
Thanks, everybody!
#Claydon, I'll check out the link. Thanks!

Comment: See above. Thanks for the trouble. I only have to select values between 2 numbers now, once I remove the texts from the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foo BETWEEN bar AND baz` is just a handy shortcut for `bar <= foo AND foo <= baz`. You can NOT expect to get "normal" results if you're comparing apples and oranges - since you're comparing STRINGS, you'll get string results. You can NOT expect the DB to able to be figure out that `A25` is greater than `A9`. It's not human.

You'll have to decompose you strings into their individual components, and compare then as "native" values, e.g.

```
('A' == 'A') and (25 == 39)
```

Comment: Agreed. I will simply remove the text portions and select between the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If all values in field Category has same format 'LETTER' + 'DIGITS' then you can create function that compare categories.

In this example I created and use schema `test`.

```
drop table if exists test.aaa;
drop function if exists test.natural_compare(s1 character varying, s2 character varying);

create or replace function test.natural_compare(s1 character varying, s2 character varying) 
returns integer 
as
$$
declare
    s1_s character varying;
    s2_s character varying;
    s1_n bigint;
    s2_n bigint;
begin
    s1_s = regexp_replace(s1, '^([^[:digit:]]*).*$', '\1');
    s2_s = regexp_replace(s2, '^([^[:digit:]]*).*$', '\1');
    if s1_s < s2_s then
        return -1;
    elsif s1_s > s2_s then
        return +1;
    else
        s1_n = regexp_replace(s1, '^.*?([[:digit:]]*)$', '\1')::bigint;
        s2_n = regexp_replace(s2, '^.*?([[:digit:]]*)$', '\1')::bigint;

        if s1_n < s2_n then
            return -1;
        elsif s1_n > s2_n then
            return +1;
        else 
            return 0;
        end if;
    end if;
end;
$$
    language plpgsql immutable;

create table test.aaa (
id serial not null primary key,
categ character varying
);

insert into test.aaa (categ) values 
('A1'),
('A2'),
('A34'),
('A35'),
('A39'),
('A355'),
('B1'),
('B6')
;

select * from test.aaa 
where test.natural_compare('A34', categ) <= 0 and test.natural_compare(categ, 'A39') <= 0
```

Comment: See my comments above. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good starting point :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3d94/2)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
create table BookList  (
id int not null auto_increment,
Title varchar(10),
Category varchar(10),
CategoryField varchar(10),
  primary key (id)
);

insert into BookList (title, Category, CategoryField) values 
('Title1','CAT1','A2'),
('Title2','CAT2','A7'),
('Title3','CAT3','A10'),
('Title4','CAT4','A12'),
('Title5','CAT5','A25'),
('Title6','CAT6','A33'),
('Title7','CAT7','A39'),
('Title8','CAT8','A50'),
('Title6','CAT6','B33')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT Title, Category
from BookList 
where substring(CategoryField,1,1) = 'A' AND
CONVERT(substring(CategoryField,2), SIGNED) BETWEEN 25 AND 39
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3d94/2/0)**:

```
|  TITLE | CATEGORY |
|--------|----------|
| Title5 |     CAT5 |
| Title6 |     CAT6 |
| Title7 |     CAT7 |
```

Comment: I realized that on each row, the columns have similar alphabets (e.g. A always go with A, B with B etc). So I'll simply strip the alphabets for each column, and make my selection between the numbers remaining. Awesome! Thanks for your time